# T-SQL passing URL as parameter is not working in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have 2 scenarios below where one case is working and another case is not I am not sure what is wrong.

Not working case which I want to implement :

```
exec[dbo].[test]
    @Alias          = 'test',
    @Pipeline       = 'testing_',
    @SBU            = 'Test',
    @LoB            = ' Test',
    @SupportChannel = 'Test',
    @Detail         = 'testing personal version',
    @Status         = 0,
    @Error          = ' no error',
    @Debug          = 1

    DECLARE @ReportURL      NVARCHAR(MAX)
    IF @Pipeline = 'testing_' 
        SET @ReportURL = N'https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/'
    IF @Pipeline = 'testing1_' 
        SET @ReportURL = N'https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/'

    DECLARE @SuccessFooter  NVARCHAR(MAX)   = 'results can be found  </br></br>' + 
    '<p><a href="'+@ReportURL+'" style="color: #FFFFFF"> Click here to view reports.</a></p>'
```

2nd the same case where I am passing the URL directly which I do not want to do as I have multiple links to pass to that parameter.

```
exec[dbo].[test]
@Alias          = 'test',
@Pipeline       = 'testing_',
@SBU            = 'Test',
@LoB            = ' Test',
@SupportChannel = 'Test',
@Detail         = 'testing personal version',
@Status         = 0,
@Error          = ' no error',
@Debug          = 1

DECLARE @ReportURL      NVARCHAR(MAX)
IF @Pipeline = 'testing_' 
    SET @ReportURL = N'https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/'
IF @Pipeline = 'testing1_' 
    SET @ReportURL = N'https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/'

DECLARE @SuccessFooter  NVARCHAR(MAX)   = 'results can be found </br></br>' + 
'<p><a href="https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/" style="color: #FFFFFF"> Click here to view reports.</a></p>'
```

Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

I want to pass the link dynamically. If I pass testing_ it should take 1st link and if I pass testing1_ it should take 2nd link.

When I execute `[dbo].[test]`, this will send me an email and the link for the corresponding website

Comment: What do you mean by "Not Working"? Do you get an error? Does it run but without the expected results? If so, what result are you getting, and what result were you expecting? Also, is this the entire code you are running, as I can't see that you have declared the variable `@Pipeline` anywhere for the 2nd part?

Comment: for the 1st case, I am getting an empty email and for the second case I am getting the details with the link. If I click on the link it works

Comment: problem is with the ReportURL where it is not accepting the URL.

Comment: Is this the full code you are running? Where do you declare the variable `@Pipeline`? Have you tried checking what the value of `@Pipeline` is before you get the `IF` statement, I expect the value is neither `testing_` or `testing1_`, therefore `@ReportURL` is not set, so remains `NULL`, then when you concatenate this with a string literal the end result is `NULL`

Comment: I got the answer pipeline parameter is stripping the special character form the input. I remove the '_ ' from the store procedure. It worked